# Apache Camel netty-http route creation fails

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty, spring-camel

I try to create simple Apache Camel route for netty-http:proxy consumer using camel-spring-boot-starter.

Here is Route definition:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:hello?period={{myPeriod}}").routeId("hello")
                .bean(myBean, "saySomething")
                .to("stream:out");
        from("netty-http:proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy").routeId("ksed")
                .to("https://www.sme.sk");
    }

}
```

The 1st timer route is working well. The 2nd if not commented out causes application not starting:

```
2023-07-24T16:22:38.078+02:00 ERROR 32604 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[From[netty-http:proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy] ->... because of No endpoint could be found for: netty-http://proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:82) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModelReifierFactory.createRoute(DefaultModelReifierFactory.java:49) ~[camel-core-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:816) ~[camel-core-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:685) ~[camel-core-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2396) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83) ~[camel-api-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2062) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111) ~[camel-api-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2081) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:313) ~[camel-core-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119) ~[camel-spring-4.0.0-20230724.063354-177.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151) ~[camel-spring-4.0.0-20230724.063354-177.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at sample.camel.MyCamelApplication.main(MyCamelApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: netty-http://proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:862) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:758) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.support.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:60) ~[camel-support-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:96) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:76) ~[camel-core-reifier-4.0.0-20230724.063354-184.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Uri in exception is modified to netty-http://proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy.

Here is my pom (extract):

```
    <properties>
        <spring-boot-version>3.1.2</spring-boot-version>
        <camel.version>3.21.0</camel.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Camel BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-netty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-netty-http-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- include camel developer console -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-console-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- include JMX that allows additional information in camel developer console -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-management-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel CLI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cli-connector-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Note: if I use camel-maven-plugin (same version 3.21.0) - given uri "netty-http:proxy://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy" works fine. Unfortunately I cannot use that plugin due to customer requirements.

Any idea what can be wrong?

Tried on Camel version 3.21.0 & 4.0.0-RC1. Also netty-http:http://0.0.0.0:8080 produces the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `camel-netty-http-starter` and `camel-http-starter` in my classpath. Please note that the right syntax is `netty-http:protocol://host:port/path` so it should rather be `netty-http:http://0.0.0.0:8080/proxy`